# How to make a bootable CD using imgburn?

Tags: installation, boot, iso, burning

What should we give in the "Advanced Bootable Disc" tab?

Comment: @Web-E Even with minimal information, I think it's clear this question is based on the idea that one must do something special to make an Ubuntu CD bootable. As you've said, that's not the case, and I think that answers the question. So I recommend posting a short answer to convey the same information as your comment (or expanding on it if you wish). Then our comments can be removed, this question will be answered, and others with similar questions can get their answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to make ubuntu ISO as bootable. It is bootable. Just use any image burner program to burn it to ISO. Burn at low speed for better results.

Please make sure you are changing the boot order from BIOS. You will have to hold down the <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or whatever key to
enter your bios settings and make the cd drive as first bootable device, (carefully) save changes,
and exit.